# PHP stucture struct[array()]

Tags: php, arrays, structure

I try to find a structure in php that will do this job:

```
$a = array(1,2);
$b = array(3,4);
$c = array();
$c[$a] = 100;
$c[$b] = 200;

$i = $c[$a] + $c[$b]; 
echo $i;
```

As you can see I have used arrays but this seems not to be correct because I get this:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs....... on line .....

What is the proper structure I should use. Can this job be done with arrays? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to use an array as key. A key can only be a number or a string. What you do now is: `$c[array(1,2)] = 100;` Solution: Depends on what you want to do. Guess is, just change `$c[$a] and $c[$b]` to `$c[] = 100; $c[] = 200; $i = $c[0] + $c[1];`

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to use an array as a key. This array has latitude and longitude. I want to use coordinates as key. If this can't be done with arrays can i use another structure?

Comment: You could `implode()` the array into a string, e.g. `$coor1 = [1, 2]; $coor2 = [2, 3];` then use them like this: `$c = []; $c[implode("|", $coor1)] = 100; $c[implode("|", $coor2)] = 200;` With this you have keys like: `1|2` or `3|4`. And access them like this: `$i = $c[implode("|", $coor1)] + $c[implode("|", $coor2)];`

Comment: Instead of string manipulation (slow and error prone) I would suggest you use a "two dimensional array" instead: `$c[1][2] = 100;`

Comment: @Rizier nice solution !

Comment: @dimitrisdiamond You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP array keys can only be integers or strings. You could achieve what you want with a multi-dimensional array

```
$a = array(1,2);
$b = array(3,4);
$c = array();
$c[$a[0]][$a[1]] = 100;
$c[$b[0]][$b[1]] = 200;

$i = $c[$a[0]][$a[1]] + $c[$b[0]][$b[1]]; 
echo $i;
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. I want one key. If i use this i will have a twodimentional array.

Comment: In that case you should probably use implode() as suggested by @Rizier123 and wrap it into a function.